# Installing Moen Flo with SharkBite. Is this bent copper, soft copper?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, copper

I was planning on installing a Moen Flo on an exposed copper supply line using sharkbites, but the pipe was slightly bent to connect it to the branch line.

Can anyone tell if this is soft copper just from looking at this picture?

[image]

Comment: What is the forecast problem whether the copper pipe is rigid or not? Can you tell by touch with some force? You need to put up more details. Or this question will be closed.

Comment: That pipe is curved, not just slightly bent.  You can get quite a variety of pipe rounding tools, including [rerounding tool for type K soft copper to be used with compression fittings](https://www.reedmfgco.com/en/products/water-services-tools-and-machines/rerounding-tools/).  Sharkbites require a very round pipe and a very straight cut to work properly so you should probably sweat or use compression fittings to switch to hard pipe before you use Sharkbites.  From the look of the device you linked you may need a slip coupling of some sort as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's soft copper tubing. I have used it when replacing old pipes in two story building where access was extremely limited. I have seen SharkBite connectors used on soft copper but it has to be perfectly round... which is sometimes difficult. I'd be switching to hard copper before using SharkBites. Personally, I wouldn't be using SharkBites at all.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like type K soft copper.

Generally  it is used as the underground supply line from the municipal source at the street to the house.

In most cases it terminates at the valve and a harder copper is used on the house side of the main valve.

Push to connect fittings need a  perfectly round pipe in order for the rubber seal inside of  it  to function as designed. **I.E. Make a good seal and Not leak.**